# Redirect page after res.write()

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to redirect page after res.write()?

Below is my code

```
res.write("<br>Login successful!<br>")
res.write(req.session.user);

res.end();
res.redirect(301, '/content')
```

It always failed:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
>   to the client

How to do it properly?

Comment: When you use `res.write` headers and output are sent therefore no more headers can't be set after output, ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT. Using `res.redirect` it will try to set the `Location` header but you already have sent the headers from write and ended the request. Leave only `res.redirect(301, '/content')` and all other server-side logic you may have.

Answer (score 0):

```
res.end();
res.redirect(301, '/content')
```

calling res.end() ends the response process. So you cannot use any response methods after that. From the [express documentation :](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end)

> Use to quickly end the response without any data. If you need to
>   respond with data, instead use methods such as `res.send()` and
>   `res.json()`.